# Why is Javascript rendering changes to DOM after completion of entire script?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>    
    <ul>
        <li>Skittles</li>
        <li>Starburst</li>
        <li>Twix</li>
    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function timeDiff(n){
            var start = now = Date.now();

            while(now - start < n*1000){
                now = Date.now();
            }
        }


        var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

        lis[0].textContent = "Text 1";
        timeDiff(2);
        lis[1].textContent = "Text 2";
        timeDiff(2);
        lis[2].textContent = "Text 3";
        timeDiff(2);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

On running the above code, the program waits for 6 second and changes the text of all three li's together.

Whereas if I run the following javascript in console:

```
console.log("Text 1");
timeDiff(2);
console.log("Text 2");
timeDiff(2);
console.log("Text 3");
timeDiff(2);
```

Then the console prints "Text 1", waits for 2 seconds, prints "Text 2", waits for 2 seconds, and prints "Text 3".

Why is Javascript behaving differently in both cases? In first case it's manipulating li's together, whereas in the second case it's printing on console one by one.

Comment: Your code is modifying the DOM, but the DOM doesn't update the browser until the entire script is finished.  Internally, it's something like "update the DOM, wait 2 seconds, update the DOM, wait 2 seconds ..... write DOM to browser."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser doesn't render changes to the DOM until JavaScript has returned to the main event loop. This allows scripts to make lots of changes to the page, and the user doesn't see all the intermediate steps, they just see the final result.

When you execute the statements in the console, it returns to the main event loop after every statement, so you see the results of that change. But when you run a script, nothing is rendered until the entire script completes.

Instead of a `while` loop, use `setTimeout` to delay actions. This doesn't block the browser while waiting for the timeout to complete.

```js
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

setTimeout(() => {
  lis[0].textContent = "Text 1";
  setTimeout(() => {
    lis[1].textContent = "Text 2";
    setTimeout(() => {
      lis[2].textContent = "Text 3";
    }, 2000);
  }, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Skittles</li>
  <li>Starburst</li>
  <li>Twix</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code in the first example is that what you are doing is called a busy wait. Browsers update the displayed html of a page after javascript finished executing. The script finishes executing after 6 seconds, so that's when you see the list items change. If you want something to happen after a set amount of time in javascript, you should be using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)